# xxx.mhtml file can't display in my website

Tags: python, html, django, mhtml

I'm writing a website with django.

There are some xxx.mhtml document in my database.

I want to show these document through my website. But it can't display normally.

I write my code like this：

`static_mhtml` is the relative path of my xxx.mhtml document.

`return render(request, static_mhtml)`

But with the same method：

`return render(request, static_html)`

`static_html` is the relative path of my xxx.html document. 


The html can display normally.

How can i solve this problem？

By the way, the .mhtml document can display in the Chrome in my desktop if i click it directly.

Is there any method to open a local document, the URL may like  `file:///xxx.mhtml`,throuth my website which the URL may like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/xxxx`.

Or how to change my mhtml document to other format such as html、image and other format that can display in my website.

Comment: If `return render(request, static_html)` works, then `static_mhtml` must contain the wrong path to the template.  Do both templates live in the same directory?  (They must not.)  What is the value of `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: The html and mhtml documents are in the same path. And the file path is included in the TEMPLATES['DIRS']. Both of them can be found, but it can't show normally. The mhtml document is encode with base64.

Comment: Then you'll have to give us more detail.  Start with the error message you get from Django.

Comment: Also, your post says that the MHTML documents are in a database, but you also say that `static_mhtml` is the relative path, implying that they are plain files.  So which is it?  Database, or plain file?

Comment: sorry, the documents not in database, they are in a plain file.

Comment: I doubt whether MHTML can be rendered as HTML documents directly

Comment: If they can't be rendered as html, then ... what are you trying to _do_, exactly?

Comment: So how to display a mhtml document in the website？

Comment: Do i need to convert the MHTML document  to HTML document first？And how to convert？